# Add label to right-angled connector -

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm try to add a label to a right-angled connector in a TikZ figure. Below is the code I'm using:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum height={1.5cm},thick,align=center},node distance=2.5cm, auto]
\node[draw] (CC) {CC};
\node[draw, right= of CC] (PC) {PC};
\node[draw, dashed, below= of CC] (AP) {DP};
\node[draw, dashed, below= of AP] (SP) {SP};
\node[draw, below = of SP] (BD) {BD};
\draw[->] (CC) to node {DM} (AP);
\draw[->] (AP.west) |- ($(AP.west) - (2.0,0)$) |- (BD.west);
\draw[->] (PC) |- (SP);
\draw[->] (AP) to node {SPa} (SP);
\draw[->] (SP) to node {Al} (BD);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is what is being output plus the label I would like to put is marked in red. 
[image]

How could this be done? I've tried putting in the usual `{text}` in `\draw[->] (AP.west) |- ($(AP.west) - (2.0,0)$) |- (BD.west);` but I'm either getting an error or the label is being misplaced.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated comment: Another way of creating that particular line is `\draw[->] (AP.west) |- ++(-2.0,0) |- (BD.west);`. Doesn't require the `calc` library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `node` in the corresponding path:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum height={1.5cm},thick,align=center},node distance=2.5cm, auto]
\node[draw] (CC) {CC};
\node[draw, right= of CC] (PC) {PC};
\node[draw, dashed, below= of CC] (AP) {DP};
\node[draw, dashed, below= of AP] (SP) {SP};
\node[draw, below = of SP] (BD) {BD};
\draw[->] (CC) to node {DM} (AP);
\draw[->] (AP.west) |- ($(AP.west) - (2.0,0)$) |- node[near start,swap] {Label} (BD.west);
\draw[->] (PC) |- (SP);
\draw[->] (AP) to node {SPa} (SP);
\draw[->] (SP) to node {Al} (BD);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For vertical positioning you can use the `($(node a)!x!(node b)$)` modifier together with the `xshift` key.

The corresponding line becomes

```
\draw[->] (AP.west) -| ([xshift=-2cm]$(AP)!0.5!(BD)$) node[red,left] {Label} |- (BD.west);
```

This way you don't have to guess how much shift you need to enter.